# Object-Oriented Programming / python3 Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I need to create instance of my classe and call the method created , how to do that ? i searched but didn't found the exact answer i need . thx

```
class Chemise:
    def __init__(self,ID,Prix,Couleur,Description,Quantite):
        self.ID=ID
        self.Prix=Prix
        self.Couleur=Couleur
        self.Description=Description
        self.Quantite=Quantite

    def Ajout_chemise(self,valeur):
        self.Quantite+=valeur

    def Diminuer_chemise(self,valeur):
        self.Quantite-=valeur

    def Affiche_info(self):
        print('ID=',self.ID);print('Prix=',self.Prix);print('Couleur=',self.Couleur)
        print('Description=',self.Description);print('Quantite=',self.Quantite)

class Shirt(Chemise):
    ??????
```

Comment: search for inheritance in python, you will get many results

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python class instance", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an instance, you can just do this

```
c=Chemise()
```

Then call whatever method you want

```
c.Affiche_info()
```

What you're currently doing is creating another class that inherits from the first